# Comparing issues with values php

Tags: php, if-statement, state

I have a problem with comparing 2 values and let 1 value change within the if statement. But ofcourse when I reload the page it picks up the first value again. I'm using this code to set some information in a database when a machine is turned on or off.

```
$urlMachineON = 'http://192.168.0.150/awp/Shredder/PLCfiles/IOmachineActive.html';

// get content
$contentMachineON = file_get_contents($urlMachineON);

//remove first 2 characters
$truncate = substr($contentMachineON, 2);

//remove last 5 characters
$MachineOn = substr($truncate, 0, -5);
//MachineON can only be 1 or 0

$currentState = 2;

if ($MachineOn != $currentState)
{
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO machineactiviteit (Time, MachineStatus) VALUES(NOW(), ?)");

$stmt->bind_param('s', $MachineOn);

    if ($stmt->execute() === TRUE) 
    {
        $currentState = $MachineOn;
        echo 'success'; 
    }
    else 
    {
        echo $conn->error;
    }

$stmt->close(); 
}
elseif($MachineOn == $currentState)
{
    echo 'do nothing';
}
```

So when I do this he will always use the if statement since the `$currentState` and `$MachineOn` are always different from each other. In C# you have something like initalize component to set the value one time to a specific value. But I haven't found anything about that in php. So my question is can I set a value only once? Or should I solve this another way?

This is how it should work:
first attempt before: `currentState = 2;` `MachineOn = 0;` after: `currentState= 0;` `MachineOn = 0;` 
second attempt before: `currentState= 0;` `MachineOn = 0;` after: `currentState= 0;` `MachineOn = 0;` 
third attempt before: `currentState= 0;` `MachineOn = 1;` after: `currentState= 1;` `MachineOn = 1;` 
 (I can change the MachineOn value with a button).

Comment: PHP is completely stateless - every time you execute the code it resets everything unless you persist that value using something like a session variable, a cookie or a database of some kind. As it stands this code will always do nothing.

Comment: I think I have to work with my database query and check last status of the machine

Answer (score 0):

Just save $currentState value somewhere. For example in file or in database.

```
    $currentState = file_get_contents('filepath'); // last saved state (check if is set!)
    if($currentState !== $MachineOn) {
        file_put_contents('filepath', $MachineOn); // Save current state
    } else {
        file_put_contents('filepath', 2); // Save other state
    }
```

This is pseoudocode. Remember to check if file exist and has value.

Comment: Yea I used the database. to get my last status